# ArchLinux boot causes blank screen with blinking cursor into screen turning on and then off after failed update

Tags: arch-linux, boot, upgrade

The full context is that after some months of not booting into Arch, I decided to do it and do a full system upgrade with `sudo pacman -Syu`.
While upgrading my system, I also had Firefox open, which shortly after (While the upgrade was still running) asked me to allow it to restart, since it had just been updated. I did it and it reopened itself and all my tabs, however this caused my CPU usage to go to 100%, and a bit after that the screen turned blank with only a blinking cursor.

I rebooted my computer, and upon doing so GRUB showed me a "can't find vmlinux" and "load kernel first" error.
I tried fixing it by getting into a installation medium, chrooting into my Arch partition and doing a `sudo pacman -Syu` from there, which at first I was unable to due to a "unable to lock database" error, which I solved by deleting it's lockfile.
That being done, I asked pacman to reinstall the `linux` package, which it did successfully, but upon rebooting again an getting past GRUB, I now encounter the same blank screen with blinking cursor, followed by my screen turning off and then on a second later, and the process repeating.

I do wish to know if I can still salvage the system or if it would be easier to just delete the partition and reinstall everything.